# Magento before applies the patch (also upgrade) how to check core file in changes or not

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, patches

Magento before applies the patch (also **upgrade**) how to check core file in changes or not. Anyone have a name of the software or any type of script to find out core file changes list.

I have Magento website version 1.7.0.2 and I did many core files changed 2 years ago but today I need to check wich file I have changed. for manually one by one check take lots of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important tool for git user >> https://tortoisegit.org/download/
                **TortoiseGit provides overlay icons showing the file status, a powerful context menu for Git and much more!**

Perfect Tool. all file and folder totally find out differents.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `n98-magerun` try **[Magento Project Mess Detector](https://github.com/AOEpeople/mpmd)**, otherwise you can create a DIFF file with

```
$ diff -urbB default_sacred_core_folder clients_core_folder | lsdiff
```

*Source: [http://inchoo.net/magento/quickly-check-if-magento-core-files-are-modified/](http://inchoo.net/magento/quickly-check-if-magento-core-files-are-modified/_)*

Comment: it's need git installation?

Comment: No. Just n98-magerun (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun).

Answer (score 0):

Use version control, specifically GIT. 
If you don't already have a git repo on your code base, init a new git repo on your codebase.

Set git to ignore filemode changes. (ignore permission changes)

Then create a branch to work in (don't work on master) 
Now download the exact same magento version you are running. In your case 1.7.0.2

Unpack onto of your codebase.

Use git status to see what changed.

Now you can also use git diff to see what was changed in each file.

Comment: any idea without git any software?

Comment: Git is software ;)

Comment: yes, i know it. but if my Magento in not install git.